# I have attempted to install netlify through npm but it fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, netlify

This is My Terminal:

```
The-Queue npm install netlify-cli -g
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/_bilal_abraham_/.npm/_logs/2020-12-28T20_10_27_065Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You can try with sudo before launching the command

Comment: It's not a problem with netlify-cli - any npm package you install globally like that should fail similarly. Ringolds Leščinskis gave good hints how to resolve the issue - you should change the way npm is installed, so root privileges are not required to install global packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok check out the following code from the queue

```
import React,{Fragment, useState } from 'react'
const Stuff = () => {   
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState("")
    return (
    <Fragment>
        <input type="text" placeholder="type to render!" onChange={e => setDesc(e.target.value)}/>
        <h1>{desc}</h1>
    </Fragment>
    )
}
export default Stuff
/*
render whatever is in the search bar in h1 onclick
use usestate

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a permissions issue. Do not force install with sudo. It's a bad practice.

Please, follow this official guide to fix your issue: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally